# Display div and table side by side

Tags: php, css, html, html-table

I have a div and a table, I wish to make both of them display side by side. after a few try, I still can't did that. the div(navbar) would be at the top-left, and the table would be at the bottom-right.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletable.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#13b4ff">

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Validation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table id='display'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>POSITION</th>
        <th>UNIT</th>
        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
        <th>NO.TELEFON</th>
        <th>NO.FAKS</th>
        <th>E-MAIL</th>
        <th>DATA</th>
        <th>REASON</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connect){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("permohonan_data");
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['postion']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['department']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['faks']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reason']?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

div css:

```
body {font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;}

div#nav {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0 auto;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100%;
}

div#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

div#nav li a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 60px 0px -30px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 3px #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;;
    background-color: #7a84d3;
    display: right-block;
}

div#nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}
```

table css:

```
table#display{
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 300px ;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 2px #888888;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:9px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:9px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:9px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:9px;
    border-top-right-radius:9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:9px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:9px;
    border-top-left-radius:9px;
}

table#display table{
    width: 0 ;
    height: 0 ;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0 ;
}

table#display th{
    padding: 5px;
}

table#display tr:hover td{
    background-color:#82c0ff;
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #82c0ff 5%, #56aaff 100%);    
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #82c0ff), color-stop(1, #56aaff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #82c0ff 5%, #56aaff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#82c0ff", endColorstr="#56aaff");  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#82c0ff,56aaff);
}

table#display tr:first-child {
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0069d3 5%, #007fff 100%);    
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0069d3), color-stop(1, #007fff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0069d3 5%, #007fff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0069d3", endColorstr="#007fff");  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0069d3,007fff);
    background-color:#0069d3;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}

table#display tr:first-child:hover {
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0069d3 5%, #007fff 100%);    
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0069d3), color-stop(1, #007fff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0069d3 5%, #007fff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0069d3", endColorstr="#007fff");  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0069d3,007fff);
    background-color:#0069d3;
}

table#display tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

table#display tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

table#display td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #56aaff 5%, #82c0ff 100%);    
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #56aaff), color-stop(1, #82c0ff) ); 
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #56aaff 5%, #82c0ff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#56aaff", endColorstr="#82c0ff");  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#56aaff,82c0ff);
    background-color:#56aaff;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    color:#000000;
}

table#display tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

table#display tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

table#display tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

I know there's something wrong with the code, but I'm at a loss as to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: could you put this in a jsfiddle.net or something like that, and try to narrow down just to the part of the code that doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried putting them both into a div and then setting the display to display:inline-block; ?

Comment: Could you explain little bit what you want menu at left and table at right bottom?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit no, I want them to be side by side. the menu at left and right bottom is result I'm getting now

Comment: @BuddhistBeast could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I was saying earlier that you could do:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletable.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#13b4ff">
<div id="wrapper"> // I am adding this <--------------------------
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Validation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table id='display'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>POSITION</th>
        <th>UNIT</th>
        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
        <th>NO.TELEFON</th>
        <th>NO.FAKS</th>
        <th>E-MAIL</th>
        <th>DATA</th>
        <th>REASON</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connect){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("permohonan_data");
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['postion']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['department']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['faks']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reason']?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>//end the wrapper <-----------------------
</body>
</html>
```

Keep a look out for the comments above. All I did was encapsulate the table and nav bar into one div. Then I will add the CSS below:

```
#wrapper{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

The CSS I have added will display the elements in a line together. In the case it does not work, try playing with the floats I.E. one needs to float left and one needs to float right. Comment below and let me know what's the status report :)

Comment: where did you put the css?

Comment: The CSS stays the same except I added the #wrapper.

Comment: put it into both of them?

Comment: Yeah, so add the div, like I did above and then add in the CSS that accompanies the div. Look for the comments I added in to add into your code.

Comment: its working, but I can't seem to set the proper margin and width for the table. do you have any idea why?

Comment: So you won't need to have any padding or margin for the table. Just play with the margin and padding elements until they fit perfectly.

Comment: Of course :) And to help you out with your CSS/HTML learnings, here is a helpful website! http://css-tricks.com/almanac/ Good luck, you can do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylenav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styletable.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#13b4ff">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Validation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top">
<table id='display'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>POSITION</th>
        <th>UNIT</th>
        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
        <th>NO.TELEFON</th>
        <th>NO.FAKS</th>
        <th>E-MAIL</th>
        <th>DATA</th>
        <th>REASON</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connect){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("permohonan_data");
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['postion']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['department']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['faks']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reason']?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two elements side by side the use one table with one td having side by side

[Check this link i have added one table](http://jsbin.com/iMixArom/1)

Or ------------------------------------

also you can have tow diff divs which will be operate like 
 One div **float:left** and another will be at **float:right**

I hope this will be help you regards....:)

---------------**[Update]**-------------------------

[Check this link using div](http://jsbin.com/iMixArom/4)

Comment: overlapped each other?

Comment: Have you checked my link?

Comment: just did, but I dont't want that to be vertical, how can I align it, as the same level as the HOME?